# How to search multiple files for many patterns concurrently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a 1000+ .txt files in various size. Let's say: 2MB - 4GB (avg. 20mb). File example looks that:

```
gene1_name1 allel1 allel2 patient_id_1
gene2_name1 allel1 allel2 patient_id_1
gene3_name1 allel1 allel2 patient_id_1
...
gene1_name1 allel1 allel2 patient_id_220
gene2_name2 allel1 allel2 patient_id_220
gene3_name1 allel1 allel2 patient_id_220
```

And unique genes I have 50k, where one gene can have many prefixes or postfixes. Let's say: MC223 could be MD_GEN_MC223 or AR_MC233_DE. Sometimes I need to re-upload some specific genes (whole line from file contains gene from pattern) to the database from files, so I write a python script.

Core function is `search_genes(list_of_genes)`. So it's getting list_of_genes, where I have a for example 1300 core names (like that MC223 without prefix, and postfix), and it's loop through list_of_files - what it's basically a list of paths to txt files - read each file line by line looking for match pattern and if it's true saves line to out.txt.

More specific:

- In file_list I have a path to txt files (ex. 400)
- In the second list I have a patterns for genes (ex. 1300)
- Function takes the second list and loops 1300 times through the file looking for patterns.
- And step above it's repeat len(file_list) times.

Generally, my code works. But if I need to get 1300 patterns from 350 files, where each file can have a 50k patients... it takes weeks. I mean, I run it on my i3 processor, use 1 core, and waiting 10-19 days. At work, we have a small cluster of 120 cores, and I tried to parallel it but I'm too low. So that's why I'm here.

How my code looks in the basic version:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    df = pd.read_csv('list_of_gene_patterns.txt', header=None)
    string_looking_for = list(df[0])

    start = time.time()
    print("SEARCHING....")

    create_SNP_list(string_looking_for)

    end = time.time()
    print("TIME:{}".format(end-start))
```

Next, I read about threading, but when I rebuild my code indeed it's divided tasks into threads, but still used one CPU. So time was the same.

Code with threading:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = pd.read_csv('list_of_gene_patterns.txt', header=None)
    string_looking_for = list(a[0])

    #I know it's dummy list divided but I just tested it:
    list1 = string_looking_for[:333]
    list2 = string_looking_for[333:666]
    list3 = string_looking_for[666:999]
    list4 = string_looking_for[999:]

    all_lists = [list1,list2,list3,list4]
    start = time.time()
    print("SEARCHING....")


    threads = list()

    for l in all_lists:
        x = threading.Thread(target=create_SNP_list, args=(l,))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()

    for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
        thread.join()

    end = time.time()
    print("TIME:{}".format(end-start))
```

Tests for each approach:

- 4 files (2,3,2,6 MB)

No threads:

- time 616 second
- out.txt size = 7.3MB

with threads:

- time 714 seconds (even worse, but I read it could be because I/O waiting)
- out.txt size = 7.3MB

But I notice that all threads were still stucks in one CPU core, so I read about multiprocessing.

I just modified code adding Pool(4), and put create_SNP_list() in pool.map() or apply (one of these works but I don't remember which one).

Test:
same files:

- time: 188sek. (it generate out.txt file, but never exit program - i closed pool)
- out.txt size 4GB (sic!)

From 13MB files, I got 4GB output. If I understand good, it's because program at same time can try to do same things, and for example, one file can process 4 times, coz each process don't know that this part is finished. Anyway, it's the only example where I got more than one CPU working code, but I drop it because of that output. I'm not good in parallel yet, and I don't even know if in my case parallel it's possible, so maybe someone can give me some advice to solve that problem?

Resume what I need:
I need to achieve much better time - hours not days, and I think the best way it's run it parallel on my cluster.

Comment: Please use internationally agreed SI units. `MB` = megabytes. `Mb`= megabits. `mb`=millibits?

Comment: @MarkSetchell done

Comment: Is `gene1_name1 allel1 allel2 patient_id_1` a file? Or 4 files? Or a directory hierarchy?

Comment: @MarkSetchell it's a file example. I looking for matching gene names. It's the first column from that file example.

Comment: So you are looking for 1300 patterns, one at a time, by looping through 1000 files 1300 times?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yep and searching line I use "is in" method, I thinking about looking for one pattern in 1000 files and then read next pattern and again look through 1000 files, but maybe I'm wrong but I think it's slower approach. But when I thinking about it: maybe that approach is better for parallel?

Comment: Try making a file called `patterns.txt` where there is one search pattern on each line, e.g. `MC233` on first line and another pattern on second line. Then `grep -f patterns.txt files`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks Mark for suggestion. It's working amazig fast, and for sure I will use just bash if I need it. I did not know that grep is so fast... but I have a problem coz program not only find needed lines but also preprocessing it, and i need it working on windows, so grep its ok for here and now, but I want to upgrade my python script to create exe app from it.

Comment: You don't want to search one pattern at a time because you will end up reading GB of data through the filesystem once per pattern = S L O O O W. Try compiling a `regex` that contains many patterns, either using a regex *"alternation"* using `|` or using a regex list of patterns. Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32286525/2836621

Comment: Thank U for answers, I think comment with grep suggestion + that last comment is full answer for my problem :)

Comment: Note that the order of the element in the regexp matters (for example if you have to parse WORD_AB and WORD_ABC at the same time).